# Does adding an auto_incrementing number to a MySQL partitioned table that is not part of the primary key, cause consistency issues?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has a primary key which does not include an auto_incrementing number. The table needs to be partitioned (on that primary key) for the overall strategy of reducing contention points.

I need to add an auto_incrementing number outside the primary key/partitions, but I am concerned about how MySQL will be able to keep the right sequenced number, if under the hood, all partitioned tables are in essence different tables and as that auto_incrementing number cannot be in a separate unique index.

So the question is, will I get consistency issues with the sequence doing this or does MySQL have a way to keep it accurate?

Comment: *or does MySQL have a way to keep it accurate?* Yes. *auto_incrementing number cannot be in a separate unique index* It does not need in UNIQUE index. Any index where AI field is the first one (in MyISAM - may be second) is enough. And all partition indices are processed as one single index in that process. Anycase you may test...

Answer (score 1):

Rarely does an app need the constraint about an `AUTO_INCREMENT` being `UNIQUE`.  Uniqueness is not guaranteed.

Sometimes it is best to turn

```
PRIMARY KEY(id),  -- (id is auto_increment)
INDEX(foo)
```

Into

```
PRIMARY KEY(foo, id),
INDEX(id)
```

The purpose is to cluster the rows based on `foo` because most of the access is done with `WHERE foo = constant`.

The `INDEX(id)` is *all* that `AUTO_INCREMENT` requires.  It does not require uniqueness; it does not require `PRIMARY KEY`.

I added `id` to the PK on the assumption that `foo` is not, itself, unique.  The combination `foo, id` is unique (assuming you are not playing games with `id`), thereby satisfying the uniqueness requirement of `PRIMARY KEY`.

Back to your question -- Sure, go ahead and add the id.  It will require

```
INDEX(id)  or  INDEX(id, ...)
```

Implementation insight...  When a table is opened, the auto_inc value is initialized by doing `SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl`.  If that table is partitioned, the code already knows how to check `MAX(id)` from each partition; then it can easily get the overall `MAX`.

MySQL 8.0 has a slight variation on that -- it saves the auto_inc value somewhere else so that after a server restart, you will not reuse any ids that got lost in what might have been a crash that necessitated rollbacks.  `DELETEing` the last id just before a graceful shutdown is another issue covered.

BTW -- See if you can use the above trick *instead of* partitioning.  I have found very few valid cases for using partitioning.  Provide more details on your case; I can probably spot whether it will help or not.

Ref:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint